# Hard Drive Not Recognized on either MAC or Windows

Tags: hard-drive

I can not read data/write data to my 2.5" external HDD.

I have removed it from the case, the reinserted it, still not recognized

But the Led light blinks continuously at 0.9 milliseconds

This particular Hard Drive is rotating smoothly, i can hear it and i felt the vibration. and there is NOT a clicking sound.

Please, what can i do to at-least recover my data?

Comment: You might wish to try GetDataBack (https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm)  . If that does not work, you may need a local recovery agency

Comment: @EdgeDev A cable partial failure (say, the data leads) would result in such a problem. 1) Does the device connect to a USB, external SATA, Firewire, Thunderbolt, or other type of connector on the PC side? 2) Is the drive SATA, SCSI, or some other interface? 3) Have you tried physically mounting the drive inside the PC (which wd bypass an ext. cable failure)?  Please click [edit] and answer 1, 2, & 3. Pls don't use Add Comment; instead, click [edit] & put these facts into the question. This will not preclude the use of DiskGenius as suggested below, GetDataBack as suggested above, or other apps

Answer (score 0):

Try opening in a partition editor to determine the HDD health, such as the free [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/), which can recover data from more file systems than can Microsoft tools. If one partition is bad, DiskGenius might still be able to recover data from others.

[image: DiskGenius]

In the image above, note that files can be recovered from the ext4 partition. Two data recovery tools are also marked, though I've not tried them.

Let us know if this works for you, and what the issue was and if data could be recovered.

Answer (score -1):

I had an external Toshiba hard drive (cheap one with propietary wire and HD connector), it suddenly failed working in Windows and Mac. Connected to a Linux machine and it came to life. In the drive some of directories were corrupted. So I used a Linux tool to recover data and got it.
Fast answer: just try connecting it to a Linux machine (after checked the wire is ok).